how run flutter app on linux with root rights
My app needs to create tun to set proxy, so it need root or admin rights.
on windows i add this line at the end of CMakeLists.txt in windows folder and it work
set_target_properties(
  ${BINARY_NAME}
  PROPERTIES
    LINK_FLAGS
    "/MANIFESTUAC:\"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'\" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS"
)

How to configure under linux to achieve similar effects?

I hope that starting the app can achieve the effect in the picture

It looks like you're trying to embed sudo into your application.  That sounds like a recipe for trouble.  Keep it as it is, and report the error sanely if the process doesn't have sufficient capability.  Certainly don't insist that it runs as root - that will piss off competent admins who have delegated permissions effectively.

i resolve this by add this to main.dart
await Process.run('pkexec', ['env']);
